# What is the best way to persist data across activities and fragments without using a database?

Tags: java, android, singleton

I'm trying to persist a list of objects across activities and fragments using the Singleton Design Pattern, but at certain times, I think when a process or activity gets destroyed by Android because of memory resources, the Singleton object is destroyed and my app crashes. I've come across this post:

[How do I make Android's Singleton object persistent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11319136/how-do-i-make-androids-singleton-object-persistent)

and to quote:

> I think a new top-level activity is made in a new process (reading
> between the lines in
> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ProcessLifecycle).
>
> Android is more likely to kill of the process of an Activity that
> lives in the background, and that includes when a top-level activity
> drops behind another.
>
> I think a better solution might be to have your Singleton
> transparently initialise itself if null, loading and saving any state
> from disk if necessary (a pretty standard singleton paradigm). There's
> no way to solve your problem with a single instance across the old and
> new activities.

Is there no way to ensure data persistence across activities and fragments without having the potential of reinitializing the data from a database?

Comment: you can use Shared preference for that i think.

Comment: Do you mean you don't want any writing to the disk at all?

Comment: No, I'll write to disk just to persist data when the app is not running, but during runtime I need the data to persist between activities without constantly writing to disk.

Comment: "when the app is not running"  When your process is killed, your app is not running, FYI.

Answer (score 1):

Shared Preferences is best for storing your application data. You can try and start here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

Comment: Is this a good way to store objects?

Answer (score 1):

- Option 1 : Shared Preferences
- Option 2 : Using Global Constant

If you want data after application close you can go for Option 1
After application close no need data you can go for Option 2